# Gravity Forms | Form Object is NULL

Tags: hooks, plugin-gravity-forms

I am trying to customize some gravity forms behavior. Therefore I've tried to hook into gforms from my theme. Unfortunately the form object is always `NULL`. Why is that the case?

Example code:

```
1)
add_action('gform_confirmation', 'myCustom_gform_confirmation');
function myCustom_gform_confirmation($confirmation, $form) {
    var_dump($confirmation);
    var_dump($form);
    die();
}

2)
add_action('gform_after_submission', 'myCustom_gform_after_submission');
function myCustom_gform_after_submission($entry, $form) {
    var_dump($entry);
    var_dump($form);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the add_action function is only going to pass 1 parameter, but you can define how many do you have / need

> $accepted_args (int) (optional) The number of arguments the hooked
>   function accepts. In WordPress 1.5.1+, hooked functions can take extra
>   arguments that are set when the matching do_action() or
>   apply_filters() call is run.

So change your code to this:

```
add_action('gform_confirmation', 'myCustom_gform_confirmation', 10, 4);
```

Comment: Yikes. That is a shame :( 
Even more so: Many thanks :)